# Prevent xml escaping in Restful (JAXRS)

Tags: java, xml, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have a restful service(jersey) that returns a url with request parameters in one of the tags. Example :

```
<url>http://abc:9080/testMe.jsp?req1=a&req2=b</url>
```

(It's part of the response)
When I get the response, I get as below ('&' becomes '& a m p;', without any space. I added space to avoid escaping here):

```
<url>http://abc:9080/testMe.jsp?req1=a&amp;req2=b</url>
```

I looked up in google and found many ways to do it in jaxb but nothing in Restful (JAXRS). Also, I tried a lame solution of adding backslash but with no success. 
How can I prevent it from happening in java 1.6?

Comment: You must escape `"'<>&` for your response to be valid XML. It's up to the client to decode XML correctly.

Comment: @Dmitri Makes sense. I hope the user understands what a well-formed xml is. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing you should change, since this is like XML works: `&` is a special character in XML and any `&` contained in text is escaped as `&amp;`

Your expected result `...=a&req2=b...` would not be a well-formed XML document, whereas the result returned by Jersey is well-formed.

When you want to access the url value in the response document, you will need to parse the response with a XML parser (e.g. into a DOM document) and the parsed document will have the url value as you expect.